# Size issue when stitching images using stitcher module

Tags: opencv, image-stitching, opencv-stitching

I tried to use the stitcher module in OpenCV to stitch images. Below is my code (core part).

```
int main()
{
    Mat img1 = imread("5.jpg");
    Mat img2 = imread("6.jpg");
    //Mat img3 = imread("11.jpg");
    imgs.push_back(img1);
    imgs.push_back(img2);
    //imgs.push_back(img3);

    Mat pano; // Mat to store the output pano image
    Stitcher stitcher = Stitcher::createDefault(try_use_gpu); // create a Stitcher object
    Stitcher::Status status = stitcher.stitch(imgs, pano); // stitch the input images together
    cout << "hello" <<endl;
    if (status != Stitcher::OK)
    {
        cout << "Can't stitch images, error code = " << int(status) << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    imshow("pano",pano);
    imwrite(result_name, pano); // write the result to the output image
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

"imgs" in the code above is a vector of Mat type.

I saw a lot of similar code the net similar to this, but I don't know why my code has a big limitation on the size of the input images. If the input images size is around 800 * 600, it works well. But when the size is 650 * 650 or 1280 * 640 or something else, the console prompt will just close very soon after the program ends. And no images are saved in "panoResult.jpg". Also no image is displayed. Visual Studio 2010 is just displaying `Image_stitching2.exe: Native' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).`  when I am debuging.

Can anyone helps with this? I really need to get progress on this since I have already spent several hours to fix it but just not correct. Any tips or help is great for me.